# Cannot create FOREIGN KEY for a table

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I'm not a professional DBA, I encountered a problem when I's attempting to create FOREIGN KEY for a specific table by the following SQL script (I'm using MySQL):

```
ALTER TABLE mmy_answer ADD CONSTRAINT fk_answer_userId FOREIGN KEY (userId) 
references mmy_user_account(id);
```

I'm sure there is no FOREIGN KEY named 'fk_answer_userId' with table mmy_answer and refered table mmy_user_account exists, the following is the error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`marry0528`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-734_5'>, CONSTRAINT 
`fk_answer_userId` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `mmy_user_account` (`id`))
```

Can anybody give me help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you have at least one row in the child table that references a non-existent row in the parent table.

If you are absolutely sure that you are okay with having a data integrity issue like that, you can add the foreign key by disabling foreign key checks before you run the ALTER TABLE command:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

And after altering the table and adding constraints set

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the problem Brady Chu is having. Try to identify the rows that have a missing reference and fix those issues. After fixing those rows (maybe link them to a dummy record if you have no other option) you can create the Foreign Key without errors.

Comment: That's what i explained above that there must be at least one row in child table that is referencing to non-existing row in parent table   , so either he can fix it by entering dummy entry in in parent table  or if he cant't enter the dummy entry then can supress the foreign_key_check for altering the table.